# Is there a way to create a connection to the server via SFTP in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, websocket, sftp

What client side code do I use in JavaScript to connect via SFTP to a server? I'm looking for a way to connect using JavaScript only.

**Update:**
It looks like it may be possible with [this](https://github.com/lukaaash/sftp-ws) using [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: Is it anonymous or do you need login credentials for the sftp connection?

Comment: From clientside you can connect to any port of any server, but you are restricted to HTTP, HTTPS and WebSocket protocols (and maybe FTP read-only, I think). SFTP (without a web server to act as an intermediary) is out of the question.

Comment: @Kaiido: Yup, forgot `file`. `ftp`, as I said, is read-only, AFAIK. SFTP is still out.

Comment: I thought SFTP was on port 22? Could you create a connection with a websocket (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can connect FTP/SFTP using ActiveXObject in JavaScript

Follow this link for more detailes https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22929415/Using-Javascript-to-invoke-FTP.html

Comment: Thanks that will work in Windows. But I'm looking for a JavaScript solution that will work in other platforms and browsers.

Comment: You may check this URL it might be help you in this case http://answers.neotys.com/questions/19533-how-could-i-connect-to-an-ftp-server-using-a-javascript 

and FTP can be implemented in nodejs also https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-server